# how to set expiry for every item in redis queue

Tags: redis

I am using jedis, a redis java client. I have a queue of string items. As per normal I am using lpush lpop rpush rpop for the necessary operations. But I will like to set expiry for each individual items in the queue. Is it possible?

Comment: No. You can only expire items at key level.

Comment: Any ways to get around this? Using other structures?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in redis [by design](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/242#issuecomment-3512819) for the sake of keeping redis simple and fast.

You can either store an expire value along with the string in the list, or store a separate list of expire times to let your application know if the key has expired.

There is also an alternative solution discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/rXXMCLNkNSs). You can store values in a sorted set with expire timestamps as scores and only select those members, whose scores are greater than certain timestamp. (This of course leaves it up to your app to clear the expired elements in a set)